# What are these wool houses?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

I just started a new Minecraft world with the [MineColonies](http://minecolonies.com/) mod and I stumbled across something I've never seen before.

[image]

A bunch of woolen buildings resembling igloos.  They all appear to be empty.

[image]

Neither the [Minecraft wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Biome) nor the [Minecolony* wiki](http://minecolony.wikia.com/wiki/MineColony_Wiki) appear to list anything about it.

**Why are these buildings here?**

---

<sup>*[Minecolony](https://sites.google.com/site/minecolony/) is the abandoned predecessor of the recently undertaken MineColonies incarnation.  MineColonies does not appear to have a separate wiki, so I used Minecolony's.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

I believe these are chicken coups but I am not quite sure...  I have seen that building before and it had lots of chickens in it.  I have also seen in a few videos that this building had chickens and they called it a chicken coup.

Comment: I don't doubt this could be the case, but could you link some sort of confirmation (official or otherwise) of this?  I haven't seen any chickens

Answer (score -1):

This looks like the Barbarian encampment to me without the barbarians.  Also other Youtubers have re-used the designs and buildings to store livestock such as chickens.